# A channel importance is `IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT` (3) when all app notifications are off

Tags: android, notifications, notification-channel

I've noticed that a channel importance is `IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT` (3) when all app notifications are off (on Android 10).
So when all app notifications are off,
`NotificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled()` returns `false`, and that is expected,
but `channel != null` returns `false` and `channel.importance` returns `3`, which corresponds to `IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT`, and that seems to be odd.
Is that expected behavior? I didn't find anything about that in [Andoid developers docs](https://developer.android.com/).